Flutter pub Error: Insufficient permissions to the resource at the https://pub.dev package
Whenever I want to run flutter pub get I am getting the following error:
flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
Because repay depends on flutter_native_splash any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed.

Insufficient permissions to the resource at the https://pub.dev package repository.
You can modify credentials using:
    dart pub token add https://pub.dev
exit code 69

As long as I'm living in Iran I thought that using VPN would solve my problem but it doesn't. Then I considered changing my DNS using Shecan or 403 would solve the problem, but it didn't. I thought changing Windows would fix it and it doesn't either.
I worked on it for a week and found that if I set DNS on the VPN network adapter it would be fixed. Still, it's not a proper solution because after I do this I can't open any website in the browser and as you might know the internet speed is shitty already so when I set these settings the speed drops to 200-300kbs.
I want to know if is there any solution for that or if I am the only one who is developing Flutter in Iran because I found nothing on the internet.
I've already tried this topic but like I said it didn't fix my problem.
Please help me because I am getting out of my mind.

Because of restriction from Pub.dev for some countries, it seems there is no way other than changing the IP. I recommend using a VPN service which open the Pub.dev or using services like "Shecan" and "403". There is no need to use both solution simultaneously.
